# A new formula relating the factorial and Riemann Zeta function resp. Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: reference-request, factorial, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

I proved the following identities involving the factorial and Riemann's Zeta function respectively the Bernoulli numbers:

$$\sum _{k=1}^{i}-{\frac {{\pi }^{-2\,k}\zeta  \left( 2\,k \right)\left( -1 \right) ^{k}}{ \left( 2\,i-2\,k+1 \right) !}}{i}^{-1}=1/2\,\sum _{k=1}^{i}{\frac {{2}^{2\,k}B_{2k} }{ \left( 2\,k \right) !\, \left( 2\,i-2\,k+1 \right) !}}{i}^{-1}=\frac{1}{(2i+1)!}$$

I'm pretty sure that this formula is already known, but can't find any reference for it. Does somebody have any reference for it?

Thank you very much for any hint.

Comment: What does $i$ mean in your notation

Comment: $i$ is just a running variable, see right hand side

Comment: So the first equation work for any $i$?

Comment: for any $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$

Comment: That's easily deduced using generating functions. In particular, using power series to express $\left(\frac{z}{2}\coth\frac{z}{2}\right)\sinh\frac{z}{2}=\frac{z}{2}\cosh\frac{z}{2}$ yields the identity with the Bernoulli numbers. It might have been noted somewhere, but I have not found a reference.

Comment: Also it's very close to the [standard recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition).

Comment: See also: [Han, Cenkci, Kurt (2004): A recurrence relation for Bernoulli numbers](http://icms.kaist.ac.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/982949.pdf), eqs. $(1.4)$ and $(1.5)$ and the associated references.